# Extract characters at a set position

Tags: string, r, truncate

I am trying to find a function that will extract characters at a certain position within a string. For example, I have a long file name with a date in it, and I want to end up with only the date:

```
'LT50420331984221PAC00_B7.tif'
```

and I want only the '1984221' portion.
I've come up with a complicated function, but was wondering if there is a more elegant solution.

Comment: I don't see how this is going to be universally possible to answer with the info provided. Does the date portion: always start after `n` characters? Always start with `19XX` or `20XX`? Always run for `n` characters? Can you provide any more information that would make this easier to answer?

Comment: Can you add your solution to the OP please?

Comment: Everything is explained in the R programming wikibook : http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/R_Programming/Text_Processing

Answer (score 22):

If you know the exact position of the date in your string you can use

```
substr('LT50420331984221PAC00_B7.tif', 10, 16)
```

Comment: If the date portion is _always_ in the same position, this is what I'd use.

Answer (score 3):

For example:

```
gsub('(.*)([0-9]+{7})[A-Z].*','\\2','LT50420331984221PAC00_B7.tif')
"1984221"
```

Here I assume that the date is 7 digits before a capital letter.

Comment: if you are assuming the length of the string, then what is the advantage to using `sub` over `substr`?

Comment: @RicardoSaporta I am not assuming the length of the string. The length is the length of a date in certain format. I assume the position of this date.

Comment: yes, we are saying the same things, just using different terms.  I was just wondering what you get from using `sub` in this specific context that you cannot have from using `substr`?

Comment: @RicardoSaporta We are not saying the same thing. But mine is a more stable solution: If the position change (incremented index for example) I will not change my code.

Comment: You can look for example for a string of 4 numbers that represent a year between "1970" and "2013" and select from there until before a capital letter (like @agstudy). That way it does not matter if the date consists of 7 or 8 numbers.